# virt-install doesn't create .img file on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, virtualization, iso, kvm-virtualization, qemu

In Ubuntu 14.04 virt-install of kvm ISO used to create .img automatically in location /var/lib/libvirt/images/ but in Ubuntu 22.04 even though vm installation was successful, the .img file didn't get generated. Below is the virt-install command I executed on 22.04:-

```
virt-install --connect=qemu:///system -n 'try_this_one' --arch=x86_64 --vcpus=8,sockets=1,cores=2,threads=4 --ram=2048 --disk bus=virtio,format=qcow2,cache=directsync,sparse=true,pool=default,size=16,io=native --description 'My product' --disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/try_this_one.iso,device=cdrom,bus=ide,perms=ro --graphics vnc,keymap=local --os-variant=ubuntuprecise --virt-type kvm --network bridge=br0,model=virtio --boot cdrom,hd --force --hvm --noautoconsole --cpu host-model
```

In Ubuntu 14.04, virt-install, will immediately create .img file as:-

```
Starting install...
Allocating 'try_this_one.img'
```

Do I need to change anything in the virt-install params in 22.04 case? Any info on how to get .img during virt-install itself will be helpful.